# Обрезать 2мерный массив по размерам другого 2мерного массива

Tags: python, numpy

есть массив:

```py
outputData= ds_sub.ReadAsArray()
print(outputData.shape) // Вывод (2748, 2748)
```

И 2 массив

```py
data= dataReader.ReadAsArray()
print(data.shape) //Вывод (1373, 2748)
```

Как я могу обрезать 1 массив (outputData) по размерам 2 массива, чтобы размер 1 массива получился тоже (1373, 2748)? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например, так или так, смотря что вы хотите

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

>>> np.resize(a, (2,2))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

>>> a[:2,:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: скорее всего автору вопроса нужен второй вариант... Его можно сделать немного более гибким, воспользовавшись `data.shape`

Comment: @MaxU я с этим всем тока разбираться пытаюсь. Имеете в виду, что прочитать размерность второго и подставить в слайс?

Comment: да, `rows, cols = data.shape; new = old[:rows, :cols]`

Comment: Ага. Спс. Я подумал, что может какой-то еще метод есть :)